# Laravel: Avoid specifying class dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

In Laravel you can do `app(UserRepository::class)` to resolve classes. I was wondering would it be okay to not have dependency injection in some classes. For instance, in the controller class, usually it goes something like this:

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
  $user = app(UserRepository::class)->create($request->validated()); // just used one time in a method

  return $user;
}
```

So I'm just using the repository class one time in that method. I was just wondering would it be okay to do this in these circumstances.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467574/in-laravel-any-downside-to-using-appmake-rather-than-constructor-injectio

Comment: ah, i missed that thread. That does answer my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Laravel, any downside to using App::make('') rather than constructor injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467574/in-laravel-any-downside-to-using-appmake-rather-than-constructor-injectio)